# Role Management in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my project i have a side menu from which I am redirecting to different pages. I have used the .NET ADMINISTRATION TOOL for the login purpose. All the pages are displayed in my side menu so that every user can view every pages. Now I want to hide some pages like "Manage Roles", "Role Authorization" etc from the ordinary users so that only the administrator can view these pages. How can I do this?

My menu is not in the master page. There is a user control called "Resources" in which the menu is created.Like this;

```
<div>
<ul>
<li><a href="Form1.aspx" title="Form1">Form1<a/>
<li><a href="Form2.aspx" title="Form2">Form2<a/>
<li><a href="Form3.aspx" title="Form3">Form3<a/>
<li><a href="Form4.aspx" title="Form4">Form4<a/>
<ul>
<div>
```

After this, this user control is added in every page. Then how can I hide some pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other friends mentioned you should use authorization. If you are using Sitemap, to prevent the links to show for a particular roles you've to use security trimming. Check the following link out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx

Comment: This will only remove the links from the page, this doesn't stop unauthorized users manually typing the URL in.

Comment: Yes, but you said it in your answer. But you didn't say how we can hide these links from the menu. So I suggested the security trimming.

Comment: I think the problem arised from lack of description in my post. Thus, I edited it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [Role Based Security](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx)

Comment: I have edited my question.The answer that u gave is not proper in my case.Please check my question again

Comment: I would suggest you look into Mehdi's answer i.e. using a Sitemap instead. It would be a lot easier to implement the feature you require.